# Python xml etree add sub element containing prefix to xml file

Tags: python, xml

I need to add an element to an existing xml file. The file define a namespace like this:

```
<Document xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" ></Document>
```

The element that i need to add:

```
<idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_main.xml" />
```

To obtain:

```
<Document xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging">
      <idPkg:Story src="Stories/Story_main.xml" />
</Document>
```

I've tried this:

```
        designmap = ET.parse(os.path.join(path, "designmap.xml"))
        designmap.getroot().append(ET.fromstring(f"<idPkg:Story src=\"Stories/Story_{self.id}.xml\" />"))
        designmap.write(os.path.join(path, "designmap.xml"))
```

But I get this error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 1, column 0
```

due to the parser not being able to find the prefix.

Is there a work around?

Comment: Upload a **VALID** xml document (as input) and a **VALID** xml (as the requested output)

Comment: The namespace declaration for the `idPkg` prefix must be present in the XML snippet that you want to add.